# добавить картинку в textView

Tags: java, android, textview

Доброго времени суток!
Как можно добавить картинку в текст, что бы было такое

...

текст текст

[картинка]

текст текст

...

Заранее количество и название картинок не известно. Т.е. тест будет как в пример, а [картинка] будет названием картинки которую нужно встать на это место.
Так вообще можно сделать?

Comment: в TextView нельзя произвольно добавлять картинки между текстом

Answer (score 1):

Картинку можно добавить:

```
TextView textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textview);
Drawable img = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.image);
img.setBounds(0, 0, 50, 50);
textView.setCompoundDrawables(img, null, null, null);
```

Но в вашем случае лучше сделать через `RecyclerView`. В интернете есть масса примеров как его реализовать.